# How can I reverse the CSS grid columns order?

Tags: html, css, responsive, css-grid

I want to be able to reverse the order of columns (the two small ones to the left, and the big one to the right). I've tried several solutions, but I didn't find one that works.

[image]

Here's the code:

```scss
.images-block-box{

    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 16px;
    grid-template-columns: 708fr 340fr;

    & > div:first-child{
      grid-row: span 2;
    }

    &.reverse{
      grid-template-columns: 340fr 708fr;

      & > div:first-child{
         order: 2; // This doesn't work (I want to place the first item at the end of the 3)
      }
    } // reverse

} // images-block-box
```

Note that I really want to reverse the order of the columns themselves, not just their dimensions.

Comment: Can you add html code too ?

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45383042/reverse-order-of-columns-in-css-grid-layout

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse order of columns in CSS Grid Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45383042/reverse-order-of-columns-in-css-grid-layout)

Comment: `//` is [not a valid comment character sequence in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479351/why-do-comments-work-in-stylesheets-but-comments-dont) (only the C style `/*  */` is). Most browsers will terminate parsing and ignore some of the CSS content. What this in the original source or only here?

Comment: That's not css, it's scss

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply adjust `grid-column` and consider `grid-auto-flow:dense;` to allow the next elements to be placed before:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 16px;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow:dense;
  margin:5px;
}

.grid div {
  min-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.grid div:first-child {
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.grid.reverse {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
}

.grid.reverse div:first-child {
  grid-column:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="grid reverse">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

> dense
>
> If specified, the auto-placement algorithm uses a “dense” packing algorithm, which attempts **to fill in holes earlier in the grid if smaller items come up later**. This may cause items to appear out-of-order, when doing so would fill in holes left by larger items.<sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#propdef-grid-auto-flow)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sum-up. The working techniques pointed out till now are:

- `grid-auto-flow: dense (container) + grid-column: 2 (first-child)`
- `grid-auto-flow: column (container) + grid-column-end: -1 (first-child)`

The rest of the code remains the same. Please take a look at the related answers.

Both are currently working well (at least in major/modern browsers).

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to *place* the big box to the last column by using `grid-column-end: -1`. See the demo below:

```css
.images-block-box {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 16px;
  grid-template-columns: 708fr 340fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.images-block-box>div {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.images-block-box>div:first-child {
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.images-block-box.reverse {
  grid-template-columns: 340fr 708fr;
}

.images-block-box.reverse>div:first-child {
  grid-column-end: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="images-block-box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="images-block-box reverse">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

> [`grid-column-end`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column-end#Values)
>
> `<integer> && <custom-ident>?`

> Contributes the nth grid line to the grid
> item’s placement. If a negative integer is given, it instead counts in
> reverse, starting from the end edge of the explicit grid.

Answer (score 0):

Then maybe you can use a different approach:

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 5fr 2fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    height: 500px;
    grid-gap: 2rem;
}

.one {
    background-color: red;
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.two {
    background-color: green;
}

.three {
    background-color: blue;
}

.reverse > .one {
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

.reverse > .three {
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
```

```html
<h1>Without Reverse</h1>

<div class="grid">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
</div>

<h1>With Reverse</h1>


<div class="grid reverse">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm using 3 elements. Try with 3 and you'll see it doesn't really work.

Comment: the new 3 items solution is not what I'm looking for, since it's not a real reverse. Please see the accepted answers.