# How to use justify-content: end in conjunction with 1fr in CSS grids?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I understand that `fr` is calculated based on available space in the grid container.  I have a situation where I have a grid container that I want to split into 5 columns.  The children however, are dynamically generated and depending on the situation, it could be 3 children or 4 or 5.  I still want to keep the 5-column grid intact with the specified `grid-column-gap`, but I want the grid to start populating the elements from the right.  Please see my code below: https://codepen.io/skepticacid/pen/dyGxaJb

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class = "grid-container">
      <div class = "grid-child">1</div>
      <div class = "grid-child">2</div>
      <div class = "grid-child">3</div>
      <div class = "grid-child">4</div>
      <div class = "grid-child">5</div>
    </div>
    <div class = "grid-container">
      <div class = "grid-child">1</div>
      <div class = "grid-child">2</div>
      <div class = "grid-child">3</div>
      <div class = "grid-child">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class = "grid-container">
      <div class = "grid-child">1</div>
      <div class = "grid-child">2</div>
      <div class = "grid-child">3</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
html{
  font-size: 16px;
}
.grid-container {
  background-color: coral;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 1rem;
  justify-content: end;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
.grid-child{
  background-color: saddlebrown;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

5 elements is the happy path.  However, when it comes down to 4 or 3 elements, I want them to be aligned similar to a `justify-content`: end or `flex-end` (so in the 4-column example, I want div number 4 to align with div number 5 above).  Also, I also want to retain the width of the column to match the ones in the 5-column width.

Is this possible through CSS grid?  Apologies, if I'm missing something glaringly obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such property to [reverse the flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45383042/reverse-order-of-columns-in-css-grid-layout) in CSS-Grid.

One solution (which does not scale nicely) is to use `nth-last-child` in this situation to designate which column is required.

```css
html{
  font-size: 16px;
}
.grid-container {
  background-color: coral;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-gap: .25rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.grid-child{
  background-color: saddlebrown;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.grid-child:nth-last-child(1) {
  grid-column:5;
}
.grid-child:nth-last-child(2) {
  grid-column:4;
}
.grid-child:nth-last-child(3) {
  grid-column:3;
}

.grid-child:nth-last-child(4) {
  grid-column:2;
}
.grid-child:nth-last-child(5) {
  grid-column:1;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-child">1</div>
    <div class="grid-child">2</div>
    <div class="grid-child">3</div>
    <div class="grid-child">4</div>
    <div class="grid-child">5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-child">1</div>
    <div class="grid-child">2</div>
    <div class="grid-child">3</div>
    <div class="grid-child">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-child">1</div>
    <div class="grid-child">2</div>
    <div class="grid-child">3</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  This works for me now.  You've got me thinking though - is it possible to achieve the same result using flexbox?

Comment: Not unless the elements are of a fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
If that you want it this way

```
direction: rtl;
```

if issue with direction hope it solve it.

last answer:

```
justify-items: center;
```

Doesn't matter.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Sorry, maybe there's something I'm not following.  justify-items only adjusts the position of each child inside the grid column.  I was looking at how to adjust the start of the whole grid.

Answer (score 0):

We can make use of `auto-fit` Which only creates columns when needed unlike `auto-fill` and the current setup which creates columns even when not needed.

This will work if we know the maximum number of columns we're going to have we'll go with 5.

Our `grid-template-columns becomes` like this:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0px,calc((100% - ( .25rem * 4)) / 5)));
```

Instead of the predefined 5 columns we calculate 5 columns from the width of the parent, Subtracting the `grid-gap`

And finally we apply `justify-content: flex-end;`

```css
.grid-container {
    background-color: coral;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0,calc((100% - ( .25rem * 4)) / 5)));
    grid-gap: .25rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.grid-child {
    background-color: saddlebrown;
    color: white;
    padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-child">1</div>
  <div class="grid-child">2</div>
  <div class="grid-child">3</div>
  <div class="grid-child">4</div>
  <div class="grid-child">5</div>
</div>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-child">1</div>
  <div class="grid-child">2</div>
  <div class="grid-child">3</div>
  <div class="grid-child">4</div>
</div>
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-child">1</div>
  <div class="grid-child">2</div>
  <div class="grid-child">3</div>
</div>
```