# How do I 'shuffle' a set of divs together using flexbox

Tags: html, css

I'm learning responsive web-development using media queries and I want to know if it's possible to move an element from one div to another without using a script.

On a desktop display it's arranged like

```
      ---------
div1 |         | div2
div3 |  image  | div4
div5 |         | div6
      ---------
```

which is what I was going for.

and on mobile screens I want

```
      ---------
     |         | 
     |  image  |  
     |         |  
      ---------
         div1
         div2
         div3
         div4
         div5
         div6
```

But I can't seem to move divs past their parent divs.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Shuffle</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="header">
          <h1>Shuffle</h1>
    </div>    
          <div id="main">
                <div class="leftBox">
                       <div class="boxItem" id="first">
                                  <p>1</p>      
                       </div>
                       <div class="boxItem" id="third">
                                  <p>3</p>      
                       </div>   
                       <div class="boxItem" id="fifth">
                                  <p>5</p>              
                       </div>
                </div>
                <div class="image">
                        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1605842581240-a0e2527d200b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ">
                </div>
                <div class="rightBox">
                       <div class="boxItem" id="second">
                                  <p>2<p>
                       </div>
                       <div class="boxItem" id="fourth">
                                  <p>4</p>
                       </div>   
                       <div class="boxItem" id="sixth"> 
                                  <p>6</p>      
                       </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/*
_______________________________________
          
          MOBILE SCREEN

_______________________________________
*/

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", Times, serif;
}

#main {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

html {
    text-align: center;
}

img{
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.image {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid gold;
    align-self:center;
     order: -1;    
}

.header {
    text-align: center;
}

.boxItem{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.leftBox{
    display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     width: 50%;
}

.rightBox{
    display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     width: 50%;
}

#first{
    order: 1;
}
#second{
    order: 2;
}
#third{
    order: 3;
}
#fourth{
    order: 4;
}
#fifth{
    order: 5;
}
#sixth{
    order: 6;
     
}

/*
_______________________________________
          
          DESKTOP SCREEN

_______________________________________
*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
     
    #first{
        order: 1;
    }
    #second{
        order: 2;
    }
    #third{
        order: 3;
    }
    #fourth{
        order: 4;
    }
    #fifth{
        order: 5;
    }
    #sixth{
        order: 6;
    }     
  
     img{
          align-self: center;
     }
  
     .image{
          align-self: center;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;   
          order: 0;    
     }
  
     #main{
          flex-direction: row;
          justify-content: space-between;
     }
  
     .leftBox{
          display:flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          justify-content: space-between;
          min-height: 100%;
          align-self: stretch;
     }
  
     .rightBox{
          display:flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          justify-content: space-between;
          min-height: 100%;
          align-self: stretch;
     }
}
```

If it's not possible to do this with css as it's written here, then is there another way to achieve this style using one flexbox?

I also have this on codepen https://codepen.io/johntarvis/pen/LYRYVmd?editors=1100 if that helps.

Comment: Are you open to changing your html? Is the number of text `divs` fixed at 6? And using some other than flex box?

Comment: oh yeah, I'm just tinkering around here: trying to find the easiest way to do things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this. by using `columns` property and set it to `2`. It's really difficult to achieve your approach without jquery. but in the image part you can set it to absolute and make it center part.

Here's a sample code.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

#main {
  position: relative;
}

.column {
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  columns: 2;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.sub_col {
  display: block;
  width: 34%;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 0 1rem;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 15;
}

.image {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.image img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .column {
    -webkit-columns: 1;
    columns: 1;
  }
  .sub_col {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .image {
    top: 0;
    transform: none;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="main">

    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1605842581240-a0e2527d200b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;q=85&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=srgb&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ">
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <div class="sub_col">1</div>
      <div class="sub_col">2</div>
      <div class="sub_col">3</div>
      <div class="sub_col">4</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

In this way your `div` elements are still in tact by numbering 1,2,3,4 and so on.

Comment: Wow, you guys are fast and your code is so compact.  I've got some studying to do.  Yes, this was what I was looking for.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@media queries` and `flexbox` to achieve the desired result:

```css
#main {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 300px;
}
#main > div { width: 33%;}
.leftBox, .rightBox {
    height: 100%; text-align: center;
    display: flex;        
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}    
img {max-width: 100%; height: auto;}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #main {
        flex-direction: column;  
        height: auto;
    } 
    #main > div { width: 100%;}
    .image {order: -1;}
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
        <h1>Shuffle</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <div class="leftBox">
            <div class="boxItem" id="first">
                <p>1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="boxItem" id="third">
                <p>3</p>
            </div>
            <div class="boxItem" id="fifth">
                <p>5</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="image">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1605842581240-a0e2527d200b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ">
        </div>
        <div class="rightBox">
            <div class="boxItem" id="second">
                <p>2<p>
            </div>
            <div class="boxItem" id="fourth">
                <p>4</p>
            </div>
            <div class="boxItem" id="sixth">
                <p>6</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Read more about ordering elements using flex on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items)

This SO related: [how can I reorder HTML using media queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42199911/how-can-i-reorder-html-using-media-queries)

Answer (score 0):

[CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) might be the way to go.

You can maintain a more logical HTML ordering of 1 - 6 and use CSS to organize the display. This also avoids messing around with absolute positioning. The one downside is if you have a dynamic number of rows and want to span the image across all of them, in which case see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42240114/4665

You will only need to give minimal styling for mobile then replace the code in your desktop media query with the below. Then tweak the style as needed.

```css
#main {
  /*Set Grid*/
  display: grid;
  /*We want 3 equal columns*/
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  /*And 3 equal rows -- Can be omitted*/
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  /*With a named area for the picture in the middle cell*/
  /*grid-template-areas: ". Pic ." ". Pic ." ". Pic .";*/
}


#main>.image {
  /*Place the image in column 2*/
  grid-column-start: 2;
  /*Place the image in the first row, span 3 rows*/
  grid-row: 1 / span 3;
  /*If Using named area, assign to the named area*/
  /*grid-area: Pic; */
}

/*Just for demo purposes, don't move this into your media query!*/
.image>img {
  width: 200px;
}

.boxItem {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Shuffle</h1>
</div>
<div id="main">

  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1605842581240-a0e2527d200b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ">
  </div>
  <div class="boxItem"><p>1</p></div>
  <div class="boxItem"><p>2</p></div>
  <div class="boxItem"><p>3</p></div>
  <div class="boxItem"><p>4</p></div>
  <div class="boxItem"><p>5</p></div>
  <div class="boxItem"><p>6</p></div>
</div>
```